# Prometheus: Label matching on substraction

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have the following Prometheus query and want the right side of my substraction to only subtract the  `container_memory_usage_bytes` for each node on the left side of the substraction.

Query:

```
sum(kube_node_status_capacity_memory_bytes) by (node) - on (instance) group_left container_memory_usage_bytes
```

The left side of the subtraction works.

But for the whole query I get

> Error executing query: found duplicate series for the match group;many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side

How can I make my query to match exactly the labels node == instance from left to right side?

Comment: Did you manage to find workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

The **RHS** has no instance label, so it's trying to match all those series to one on the **LHS**.
You have to also add **sum** before listing `container_memory_usage_bytes` metric, - `sum(container_memory_usage_bytes)`.

Please take a look here: [prometheus-metrics](https://github.com/openshift/cluster-monitoring-operator/blob/master/assets/prometheus-k8s/rules.yaml).

Useful article: [label-proportions](https://www.robustperception.io/using-group_left-to-calculate-label-proportions).

Comment: If I add the *sum* function to the *RHS* container_memory_usage_bytes, I will subtract the sum of all container memory bytes of all nodes from one node (from LHS). This is not what I want. I am getting negative end values. I want to subtract each container memory bytes *per node* from each corresponding node.

Comment: I fixed it by the label_replace function.
But I still don't have the right metric, the right side values of  `container_memory_usage_bytes` has too high values, I get negative values in the summary.